# ActiveRecord-like ORM for Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, activerecord, orm

Is there any ORM that wraps up CoreData and lets developer just deal with domain logic? Like what ActiveRecord does in Ruby on Rails.

AFAIK, there are [Objective-Record](https://github.com/mneorr/Objective-Record) and [MagicRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) that handle querying and persistence nicely.

How about validation and association, is there an open source project out there that provides these features?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should not wrap Core Data.  Core Data is abstracted away already and adding another layer on top of it is just going to make your code cumbersome and error prone.

Core Data != ActiveRecord and if you are going to do iOS development it is best if you learn the paradigms of Objective-C/Cocoa instead of trying to avoid them.

Comment: Agree, CD is already an adapter, it helps your code be independent from the persistent storage and hooks up nicely with your domain models. However I find it repetitive like assigning fields, create association and validation manually. I guess mobile application DB schema is not as complex as web app's so this isn't too bad.

Comment: Xcode and Mogenerator both have code generation abilities to avoid that repetitiveness.  Or you can just use KVC and no code generation is required.